# bundle configuration xsd (bundleconfiguration.xsd)

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have a question I will be glad for correct answers. What is the operation of these three lines in the below code ?

1. targetNamespace="http://www.yazilim.com/bundleconfiguration/"
2. xmlns="http://www.yazilim.com/bundleconfiguration/"
3. xmlns:mstns="http://www.yazilim.com/bundleconfiguration/"

Comment: /The bundlecondifuration.xsd is the schema file that defines the structure of an xml file, and valid types for the properties.  Normally there is a namespace that specifies the prefix (item before the colon) and the URL where the schema file is located.  In your case the it appears the actual file name is missing and the URL folders are only specified.

Answer (score 0):

The value of targetNamespace is simply a unique identifier, typically a company may use their URL followed by something descriptive to qualify it.

In principle the namespace has no meaning, but some companies have used the URL where the schema is stored as the targetNamespace, and so some XML parsers will use this as a hint path for the schema:

```
targetNamespace="http://www.microsoft.com/CommonTypes.xsd"
```

Comment: Thank you bro, If I delete this part of schema, the three lines then, will this schema work ?

Comment: It depends on how you are using it, for example: The xmlns attribute is required in XHTML, invalid in HTML 4.01, and optional in HTML5.

Comment: Ahmed bro, there is one .xsd schema in every class library, I am not sure why it is being used, can you give some information ?

Comment: When creating an XML schema we make use of the elements and attributes specified in the XML Schema standard. For this to be possible we must include in the root element of the schema (the “schema” element) a reference to the namespace “http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema”. This is done by including the "xmlns" attribute in the "schema" element:

Comment: • xmlns: identifies the namespace to which the components included in the scheme belong, optionally assigning a prefix (this prefix is ​​usually “xs” or “xsd.” Thus, the statement
xmlns: xs = ”http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema”
indicates that the elements and types of data used in the scheme come from the namespace “http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema”, which is assigned the prefix “xs”.

Comment: In addition, we can make the scheme we are creating associated with its own namespace (target namespace). To do this, you can use the targetNamespace attribute of the “schema” element:
which creates a namespace to which the elements defined in the scheme belong.